# How to use lag function of SQL in this situation?

Tags: mysql, sql, row, lag

After trying many hours, i couldn't get the answer of this. These are my columns below and i have formula to calculate values of MSF column.

```
Sr    open      high     low       closed     MSF
-----------------------------------------------------   
1    6107      6116.15   6022.3   6048.25    5214
2    6172.75   6181.05   6124.4   6146.35    Null
3    6141.35   6141.35   6062.35  6079.8     Null
4    6030.9    6051.2    5883.6   5904.6     Null
5    5901.3    5907.25   5740.95  5762.85    Null
6    5767.95   5842.6    5698.2   5754.1     Null
7    5800.05   5874.2    5711.3   5863.25    Null
8    5850.75   5857.75   5736.7   5751.9     Null
9    5752.1    5833.65   5639.65  5654.55    Null
```

I am trying to fill last column named MSF. Here is the formula for calculating MSF values for each row

`(closed - previous_value_of_MSF) x 0.33 + previous_value_of_MSF`

I am having tough time to get previous row values of MSF. Please help
Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag


Can you please share SQL that you have written

Comment: Formula i have given is theorotical formula. We need to get previous value from MSF column.

Comment: Order by Sr but in question it is not in order by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task cannot be solved in single query form - it is iterational. So either recursive CTE or user-defined variable must be used (or SP). For example:

```
SET @msf:=0;

SELECT *, 
       @msf := CASE WHEN msf IS NULL
                    THEN (closed - @msf) * 0.33 + @msf
                    ELSE msf
                    END AS new_msf
FROM sourcetable
ORDER BY Sr
```

Update:

```sql
SET @msf:=0;

UPDATE sourcetable
SET MSF = ( @msf := CASE WHEN msf IS NULL
                         THEN (closed - @msf) * 0.33 + @msf
                         ELSE msf
                         END )
ORDER BY Sr;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b90b603447523bd55b3cd9bff9d3d532)

PS. Using recursive CTE seems to provide more expensive solution.

Comment: @NitinKhandagale Updated, fiddle added.

Comment: Assigning variables in a statement other than `SET` is present for backward compatibility but subject to removal in a future version as of MySQL 8.0.

Comment: can you please tell me what this code gives you ? Previous value of MSF column ?

Comment: @Nick That's true. When this happens, we'll have to use recursive CTEs.

Comment: and how can i use this value in formula above ?

Comment: Probably best to offer that alternative too then... :) it also has the benefit of being compatible with other SQL flavours

Comment: @NitinKhandagale Yes. User-defined variable stores the value which was assigned to it when previous row was processed. ORDER BY clause ensures correct processing order. Answer edited, your formula (directly, as-is) inserted. Update query added (pay attention - it is multi-query, because is consists from 2 separate queries).

Comment: I used the second one and i got this warning from SQL

Comment: 1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'

Comment: @NitinKhandagale This is warning for SELECT. You may remove value-assigning subquery but add assigning query like in UPDATE - the warning will disappear.

Comment: Although your update code worked like a charm. You did the entire process in just few lines of code. What a genius.

Comment: @NitinKhandagale Do not pay attention - this influences nothing. The proposed alternative SET and SELECT INTO are not applicable to UPDATE.